# Omit one column in ls -hal

Tags: ls, text-formatting

How do I omit the `group` column in the output of `ls -hal`?

I was using `ls -hal|cut -f4 --complement -d ' '` and it works find most of the time, but if I run it in `/`  I get scrambled output:

```
drwxr-xr-x  25 root 4.0K Dec 21 06:08 .
drwxr-xr-x  25 root 4.0K Dec 21 06:08 ..
drwxr-xr-x   root root 4.0K Jan 12 06:17 bin
drwxr-xr-x   root root 4.0K Jan 16 10:36 boot
drwxrwxr-x   root root 4.0K May  1  2018 cdrom
-rw-------   root root  56M May  1  2018 core
drwxr-xr-x  20 root 4.7K Jan  6 17:54 dev
drwxr-xr-x   root root 4.0K Oct  9 15:14 .dotnet
drwxr-xr-x 154 root  12K Jan 16 10:36 etc
drwxr-xr-x   root root 4.0K Nov 24 19:39 home
```

(I can't figure out why this happens, `ls -hal` alone gives

```
drwxr-xr-x  25 root root 4.0K Dec 21 06:08 .
drwxr-xr-x  25 root root 4.0K Dec 21 06:08 ..
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4.0K Jan 12 06:17 bin
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root 4.0K Jan 16 10:36 boot
drwxrwxr-x   2 root root 4.0K May  1  2018 cdrom
-rw-------   1 root root  56M May  1  2018 core
drwxr-xr-x  20 root root 4.7K Jan  6 17:54 dev
drwxr-xr-x 154 root root  12K Jan 16 10:36 etc
```

)

I also tried `awk '{print $1,$2,$3,$5,$6,$7,$8,$9}'` but that always messes up the alignment:

```
drwxr-xr-x 25 root 4.0K Dec 21 06:08 .
drwxr-xr-x 25 root 4.0K Dec 21 06:08 ..
drwxr-xr-x 2 root 4.0K Jan 12 06:17 bin
drwxr-xr-x 3 root 4.0K Jan 16 10:36 boot
drwxrwxr-x 2 root 4.0K May 1 2018 cdrom
-rw------- 1 root 56M May 1 2018 core
drwxr-xr-x 20 root 4.7K Jan 6 17:54 dev
```

Comment: Just for consideration, if you want more control over the fields, you could piece together your own `ls` with a variation of `stat -c '%A %h %U %s %y %n'`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are specific `ls` options to hide the group column.  From [ls(1)](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ls):

> `-G`, `--no-group`
>
> in a long listing, don't print group names
>
> `-o`
>
> like `-l`, but do not list group information

So you could use either `ls -hao`, or `ls -halG`.

Comment: Also, with `cut`, every instance of the delimiter character matters.

Comment: Oh, i read somewhere that you cannot select or unselect individual columns, but I guess there is an exception for that column. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you the problem is that there are multiple single spaces in the result of
*ls -alh /*. Meaning that the field 4 is a different one.

What you can do is to aggregate the spaces into one:

```
ls -alh / | sed 's/\s\s*/ /g' | cut -f4 -d' ' --complement
```

But be aware that it will also remove any potential double space from the file names.

You can also learn more from this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7142735/how-to-specify-more-spaces-for-the-delimiter-using-cut):

Friendly reminder to look at your commands options. As in this case, the result can be simply achieved with the command given by JigglyNaga.